# How to fit Pluto.jl output cell to DataFrame size

Tags: dataframe, julia, pluto.jl

When I display a DataFrame in Pluto.jl a scrollbar appears. Does somebody know how to make my output cell bigger/fit my dataframe?

[image]

Comment: I asked the same question on the [julia discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/dataframe-doesnt-fit-output-block-pluto-jl/57125).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the css of Pluto to prevent the issue. Adding a cell with:

```
html"""<style>
pluto-output.scroll_y {
    max-height: 450px; /* changed this from 400 to 450 */
}
"""
```

changes this:
[image]

to this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the dataframe to html, Pluto should display it as an entire HTML table:

```
using BrowseTables
...
df = select(dfs[1], :sample)
HTMLTable(df)
```

Comment: Thnx for the suggestion. Unfortunatly this crashes my notebook. I assume because my dataframe contains a few million records...  Just for the record, I get these kind of errors: `[1:0x22ba00000000]    22654 ms: Scavenge 3816.4 (3953.0) -> 3815.7 (3960.3) MB, 15.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.639, current mu = 0.586) allocation failure 
`

Comment: Btw, I reported the issue at the BrowseTables github.

Comment: Seems like the scrollbar makes good sense for a table that size :).

Comment: Would make more sense if the scrollbar was not needed until clicking on the "... more" for showing more rows than the standard first 10 + the last. Please suggest this in the Pluto improvement suggestion box in the bottom!